# Make error - Installing RVM on Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, rvm, osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to install RVM on my Snow Leopard 10.6.8, using this:

`\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

And I get this error:

```
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/Villa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a    while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #extracted to /Users/Villa/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0 (already extracted)
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #configuring
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #compiling
Error running 'make -j2', please read /Users/Villa/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

And the make.log errors begins here:

```
In file included from openssl_missing.c:22:
openssl_missing.h:71: error: conflicting types for ‚ÄòHMAC_CTX_copy‚Äô
/Users/Villa/.rvm/usr/include/openssl/hmac.h:102: error: previous declaration of      ‚ÄòHMAC_CTX_copy‚Äô was here
openssl_missing.h:95: error: conflicting types for ‚ÄòEVP_CIPHER_CTX_copy‚Äô
/Users/Villa/.rvm/usr/include/openssl/evp.h:503: error: previous declaration of ‚ÄòEVP_CIPHER_CTX_copy‚Äô was here
openssl_missing.c:27: error: conflicting types for ‚ÄòHMAC_CTX_copy‚Äô
/Users/Villa/.rvm/usr/include/openssl/hmac.h:102: error: previous declaration of  ‚ÄòHMAC_CTX_copy‚Äô was here
openssl_missing.c:122: error: conflicting types for ‚ÄòEVP_CIPHER_CTX_copy‚Äô
/Users/Villa/.rvm/usr/include/openssl/evp.h:503: error: previous declaration of ‚ÄòEVP_CIPHER_CTX_copy‚Äô was here
make[2]: *** [openssl_missing.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
compiling psych_emitter.c
compiling psych_parser.c
compiling psych_to_ruby.c
compiling psych_yaml_tree.c
linking shared-object psych.bundle
installing default psych libraries
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Please tell me everything you need from me to get a solution

UPDATE #1

I try to install it doing:

> rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/bin

And I get this

```
Error running '__rvm_rm_rf /Users/Villa/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p392',
please read /Users/Villa/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p392/remove.src.log
/Users/Villa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392 has already been removed.
Installing requirements for osx/10.6/i386, might require sudo password
Skipping `brew update` make sure your formulas are up to date.
-bash: /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Permission denied
-bash: /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Permission denied
Doing /usr/local/etc/openssl
cert.pem => 77ee3751.0
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/Villa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392, this may take  a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p392, this may take a while depending on your   connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #extracted to /Users/Villa/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p392 (already  extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #configuring...
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/Villa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392 --with- openssl-dir=/usr/bin --with-opt-  dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libxml2:/usr/local/opt/lib    xslt:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl:/usr/local/opt/sqlite --disable-  install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',
please read /Users/Villa/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p392/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you use MacPort or homebrew? do you have openssl installed?

Comment: I'm using homebrew, and yes, I have openssl-1.0.1e installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try installing with `--with-openssl-dir=/path/to/openssl` with the location of your installed openssl version.

more over you can look at this https://rvm.io/packages/openssl/

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure which is the location of my openssl, how could I find it?

Comment: in terminal, `which openssl`

Comment: try installing with `sudo`

Comment: The installation was completed without errors! How could I check if everything is alright?

Also, I need to install rails, what should I do?

Comment: I get this:
`MacVilla:~ Villa$ ruby --version`
`ruby 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371) [i686-darwin10.8.0]`

Comment: UPDATED:
I did `rvm use 1.9.3 --default` and now it's updated!

I can't vote you because I'm new, if I get my 15 reputation points I'll vote you, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got mine to work with the following code I found on MacRuby's site:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

If you're using an Xcode version later than 4.3 this will configure the path for installations.