# Brew warning / pkg-config $PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew, pkg-config

I'm trying to install Ruby by following this guide ( [How to install...](http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/) )

But when I do

```
brew doctor
```

I get this

```
Warning: You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config

`./configure` may have problems finding brew-installed packages using
this other pkg-config.
```

I've previously installed Rails through RailsInstaller (because I had problems with RVM -> [see my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178155/make-error-installing-rvm-on-snow-leopard) ), but then I've upgraded my OSx from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion, so I'm following this guide.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever `/opt/sm/...` is, remove it from your path.

Comment: Finally, I've installed it in another way. Thanks!